# Loopback4: Can't query Postgres array value using inq

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs, loopback4

Working with LB4 framework and Postgres for DB, using **"loopback-connector-postgresql": "^3.7.0"** for DB connectivity and facing issue while using **find** query with **where** operator to fetch list of data by matching value in an array and the query used is shared below,

sample table data:

```
[{id: 1,
roll: [1,4]
},{  
id:2,
roll: [1,3],
},{
id:3,
roll: [2,4]
}]
```

In model roll marked mandatory

Query used:
`this.repository.find({where: { roll: { inq: [4] }}});`

Expected output:

```
[{id: 1,
roll: [1,4]
},{
id:3,
roll: [2,4]
}]
```

for the above code snippet typescript in loopback4 throws the below error

```
*Argument of type '{ where: { roll: { inq: number[]; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Filter<ModelRow>'.
  Types of property 'where' are incompatible.
    Type '{ row: { inq: number[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Condition<ModelRow> | AndClause<ModelRow> | OrClause<ModelRow> | undefined'.
      Type '{ row: { inq: number[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Condition<ModelRow>'.
        Types of property 'row' are incompatible.
          Type '{ inq: number[]; }' is not assignable to type 'PredicateComparison<number[]> | (number[] & string) | (number[] & number) | (number[] & false) | (number[] & true) | (number[] & Date) | undefined'.
            Type '{ inq: number[]; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2345)*
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue at the moment. Did you find a fix?

Comment: @Rizz no fix found and eagerly waiting for the loopback communities response which seems to be questionable

Comment: @sunilsmith Most of the community is in the community Slack (which the link you can find on the LoopBack website) and GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, but with string. Hacked it with cast to any and custom wrapper. May be it's possible to hack numbers in this way too. Dirty solution

```
where: {rolls: {inq: [`"{${rollValue}}"`] as any}},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Postgresql use the `ilike` filter

```
where: {rolls: {ilike: `%${rollValue}`}}
```

`inq` is a filter operator commonly used for non-relational databases like MongoDB.

`ilike` is a filter operator typically used for relational databases like PostgreSQL